# Compatibilidad de versiones APK - Ionic

Tags: ionic

Buen día para todos,

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en ionic 3  y me surge la duda de como se maneja en este Framework la compatibilidad de las APK que se generan con respecto a las versiones de Android. Normalmente en Android Studio al iniciar un proyecto, uno selecciona la versión mínima compatible, pero en Ionic no he encontrado como se maneja este tema.

Agradezco si alguien me puede dar una indicación de como es la compatibilidad de las versiones. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de los proyectos de Ionic, existe un archivo en la carpeta raiz llamado `config.xml` donde puedes agregar el target

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
```

Donde le indicas la API minima requerida para tu aplicación